# AWS CloudFront Behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've been setting up aws lambda functions for S3 events. I want to set up a new structure for my bucket, but it's not possible--so I set up a new bucket the way I want and will migrate old things and send new things there. I wanted to have some of the structure the same under a given base folder name `old-bucket/images` and `new-bucket/images`. I set up CloudFront to serve from  `old-bucket/images` now, but I wanted to add `new-bucket/images` as well. I thought the behavior tab would set it such that it would check the `new-bucket/images` first then `old-bucket/images`. Alas, that didn't work. If the object wasn't found in the first, that was the end of the line.

Am I misunderstanding how behaviors work? Has anyone attempted anything like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is expected behavior. An `origin` tells Amazon CloudFront where to obtain the data to serve to users, based upon a prefix, suffix, etc.

For example, you could serve `old-bucket/*` from one Amazon S3 bucket, while serving `new-bucket/*` from a different bucket.

However, there is **no capability to 'fall-back' to a different origin** if a file is not found.

You could **check for the existence of files** before serving the link, and then provide a different link depending upon where the files are stored. Otherwise, you'll need to put all of your files in the location that matches the link you are serving.